# Getting "Unknown error 2" when running BusyBox applets compiled against uClibc

Tags: embedded, toolchain, busybox, buildroot, uclibc

I am trying to make an embedded Linux for a SuperH processor board. I am using the Buildroot 2012.2 toolchain with uClibc.

All compiles fine but when I try to run some of the BusyBox applets (for instance 'ls' or 'mount'), I get an error like this:

```
ls: : Unknown error 2
```

For 'ls' in particular it writes this error number-of-files-in-folder times.

Do you have any ideas what might be causing this? No one on the internet seems to have the same problem and I am crawling the configs for several days without luck.

I believe the error might be caused by misconfigured uClibc but it is just my guess.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I enabled several error message options in uClibc and now I get "no such file or directory" error.

Comment: Not an answer, so I'm leaving this as a comment. Can you fit strace on board? If so, try running one of the busybox applets under strace. It's my first port of call for problems like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

The first and most important problem was, that I have over-optimized uClibc so all reasonable error reports were not included. If you are reading this and have same problem, switch error messages on. They are quite small and very useful.

After resolving human readable error reports, I realized, that the putchar function was disabled. Enabling it solved the problem.

To future generation I advise extreme caution, which features of uClibc you decide to disable, unless you want to spend several days finding an unexpected bug.